# FileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier) returning nil in unit testing

Tags: swift, ios-app-group

During unit testing the following function returns nil meaning my group id is invalid. `fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:"group.myGroupId")`However if I run the same code on a sim or a device it works perfectly.

What am I missing in order to use app groups during unit testing?

Comment: Hi @mufumade did u manage to fix this issue ?